# python dissolve by field error

Tags: geoprocessing, arcgis-10.2, python-2.7, dissolve

I would like to dissolve a feature class by a field. When I run the code, I receive an error that says, "invalid topology [out of memory]" I have 16GB of RAM and terabytes available on the hard drive.

Here is my code:

```
#Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set environment settings
env.workspace = "Q:/LandTrendr_04/lt_ancillary/landtrendr_file_geodatabase/templates_testing/LandTrendr_GRPO_python.gdb/"

# Set local variables
inFeatures = "raster2polyg"
outFeatureClass = "polydissolve"
dissolveFields = ["UNIQUE"]

# Execute Dissolve using UNIQUE as Dissolve Fields
arcpy.Dissolve_management(inFeatures, outFeatureClass,dissolveFields,"","MULTI_PART", "DISSOLVE_LINES")
```

I would like to dissolve on the 'UNIQUE' field, no stats, create multipart polys, and dissolve lines.

I've tried to run this same tool through the toolbox and it works just fine. I would like to have this in a python script to help with my workflow.

Here is the output from the cmd prompt when I run the script. [image]

Thanks

-al

Comment: I don't think "DISSOLVE_LINES" is applicable to Polygon features, only Polyline features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory errors can very often be resolved using [64-bit background geoprocessing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002100000040000000).  This is not necessarily installed by default, especially if you are running ArcGIS through a larger organization such as a University.  You will need to check to see if the following exists on your system:

> C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.2

Also, when defining the [workspace](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w00000002000000) with the `arcpy.env.workspace` method, you need to make sure the path does not end with a "/".  Otherwise, when Python appends your filename to your workspace path in the dissolve function, the result would be (incorrectly) the following:

```
"Q:/LandTrendr_04/.../LandTrendr_GRPO_python.gdb//polydissolve"
```

Therefore, replace:

```
env.workspace = "Q:/LandTrendr_04/.../LandTrendr_GRPO_python.gdb/"
```

with:

```
env.workspace = "Q:/LandTrendr_04/.../LandTrendr_GRPO_python.gdb"
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I fixed the error, however I still receive the same error. "arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function. Invalid Topology [Out of memory.] Failed to execute (Dissolve).

Comment: Try running the script again, this time using "SINGLE_PART".

Comment: The same error. Could it be running out of memory? Doesn't seem possible with 16 GB of RAM.

Comment: If you're running ArcGIS 10.1 or 10.2, consider running this as a 64-bit background process.  More info here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002100000040000000

Comment: @AlK If you think you may be running out of memory then you can watch the process using Task Manager to see if its memory usage is continuing to build prior to the error.  As a test you could also try Select-ing half your features into a test dataset to see if being able to Dissolve that without a problem suggests that your feature class is just too big for your amount of memory.  In the latter case I think you should submit your dataset to your local Esri support.  Trying 64bit background geoprocessing is a good idea but that has not played nicely with large models for me.

Comment: I subset the original feature class to something smaller and it worked fine. So, it's a memory issue. I followed the link to running python in 64bit mode, but I couldn't figure it out. I only have one folder w/in c:\Python27 and it is ArcGIS10.2, I don't have an ArcGISx6410.2 folder, like it shows in the link Aaron provided. Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: The solution to this problem for me was to install and run 64 geoprocessing which also installs 64bit python. I then called the 64bit python directly from the command line when I ran my script. To see how to run as 64bit process, follow @Aaron's link. Thanks Aaron! PolyGeo was able to lead me to the problem by having me try to run the process with a smaller dataset. Thanks PolyGeo!

Comment: @Al K I updated the answer with information about using 64-bit background geoprocessing.  Thanks for following-up on this.